# returning 410 response header for deleted pages

Tags: .htaccess

I accidently trashed my website and want to remove all indexed urls except the home page from Google and start over. Can anyone tell me how to create a .htaccess rewrite rule to return a 410 response header for all urls except the home page?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule !^(?:index\.(php|html)|)$ - [L,R=410]
```

That will also cover `index.php` and `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was looking all over the place trying to find an answer to this. What about the home page? I don't want it to return a 410 error.

Comment: @user2205555 since you didn't provide what your homepage was, I assumed it was "index.php" or "index.html". If it isn't then replace the index.php part of the regex with your homepage.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info. It's a Wordpress site, so the homepage is http://mydomain.com. I just want to make sure I get it right.

Comment: @user2205555 the `/` means there's no URI, and that's covered by the optional "index.php". Apache will internally route `/` to `/index.php`, which is also handled. Did you try the code?

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting a 404. Where exactly should I put the code you gave me? Also, is that meant to be a forward slash or backslash?

Comment: I mean, does it matter where in the .htaccess file I put the code?